# How to search and export value with python and re?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to export some value from the text to a txt file.
my text has this form:

```
"a='one' b='2' c='3' a='two' b='8' c='3'"
```

I want to export all the value of the key "a"
The result must be like

```
one
two
```

Comment: so you have a text which is a lot of things in the format "X=Y" and you want to get all the "Y" where the "X" is "a" ?

Comment: @InbarRose: Yes exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex is very easy to understand:

```
pattern = r"a='(.*?)'"
```

It doesn't use lookarounds (like `(?<=a=')[^']*(?=')` ) - so it's very simple ..

Whole program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

text = "a='one' b='2' c='3' a='two' b='8' c='3'"
pattern = r"a='(.*?)'"

for m in re.findall( pattern, text ):
  print m
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what is the ? in (.*?) for?

Comment: this is to make the dot non-greedy .. this means, that it just matches the characters until the following can be matched ... If you don't do this your result will be: `one' b='2' c='3' a='two' b='8' c='3` because the last closing tick is until the `3` from `c='3` and in the greedy mode it matches as long as it can...

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct for your particular case, but I think a regex with lookbehind/lookahead is a more general solution, i.e.:

```
import re

text = "a='one' b='2' c='3' a='two' b='8' c='3'"

expr = r"(?<=a=')[^']*(?=')"

matches = re.findall(expr,text)
for m in matches:
    print m  ##or whatever
```

This will match for any expression between single quotes preceded by a=, i.e. a='xyz', a='my#1.abcd' and a='a=5%' will all match

Comment: I think I would take me a while to understand the syntax of your pattern!

Comment: Let me explain: ``(<?=a=')`` matches "a='", but this does not become part of the actual match (lookbehind). ``[^']*`` matches everything except a single quote, as often as possible. ``(?=')`` matches ONLY a single quote, but the single quote also does not become part of the match (lookahead). So everything between the single quotes, but not including the quotes themselves, is matched. I hope that helped?

Comment: why not use this one `a='(.*?)'`? It is much easier to understand for a beginner as those lookarounds ( althought they are sexy :) )

Comment: Well, that would include "a='" in the actual match expression and he only wants to output the content *between* the quotes. So there would have to be a separate step in the code where you lstrip the "a='" and rstrip the "'" before writing to file. But you're right, that may be more straightforward in this particular case

Comment: of course not, because there are these matching parantheses around my "non-greedy" dot ;) test the code in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034852/how-to-search-and-export-value-with-python-and-re/12035534#12035534

Comment: oic. Yes, you are correct. Feel free to edit my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r"'([a-z]+)'")

f = open('input')
text = f.read()

m = r.finditer(text)

for mm in m:
    print mm.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

thought i would give a solution without re:

```
>>> text = "a='one' b='2' c='3' a='two' b='8' c='3'"
>>> step1 = text.split(" ")
>>> step1
["a='one'", "b='2'", "c='3'", "a='two'", "b='8'", "c='3'"]
>>> step2 = []
>>> for pair in step1:
    split_pair = pair.split("=")
    step2.append([split_pair[0],split_pair[1]]) 
>>> print step2
[['a', "'one'"], ['b', "'2'"], ['c', "'3'"], ['a', "'two'"], ['b', "'8'"], ['c', "'3'"]]
>>> results = []
>>> for split_pair in step2:
        if split_pair[0] == "a":
            results.append(split_pair[1])   
>>> results
["'one'", "'two'"]
```

not the most elegant method, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another non-regex solution: you could use the `shlex` module and the `.partition` method (or `.split()` with `maxsplit=1`):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> s = "a='one' b='2' c='3' a='two' b='8' c='3'"
>>> shlex.split(s)
['a=one', 'b=2', 'c=3', 'a=two', 'b=8', 'c=3']
>>> shlex.split(s)[0].partition("=")
('a', '=', 'one')
```

and so it's simply

```
>>> for group in shlex.split(s):
...     key, eq, val = group.partition("=")
...     if key == 'a':
...         print val
... 
one
two
```

with lots of variations of the same.